pythontex in newenviron
Is it possible to get pythontex to work in a newenviron? The following is a min working example that generates an error.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage[makestderr]{pythontex}


\newcommand\boxparA[1]{
 \[
  \framebox[\textwidth][c] {
   \parbox[]{\dimexpr\textwidth - 0.25cm} {#1}
  }
 \]
}

\NewEnviron{foo}%
  {\vspace{-1mm} \global\let\tmp\BODY\aftergroup\doboxparA}

\newcommand\doboxparA{%
  \let\quote=\oldquote
  \let\endquote=\endoldquote
  \boxparA{\tmp}
}%


\begin{document}

foo:
\begin{foo}
\begin{pycode}
print(42)
\end{pycode}
\end{foo}

\end{document}

Error message:
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (./pythontex-files-main/main.pytxpyg)
! Argument of \FV@BeginScanning has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.32 \end{foo}
              
? 

Compiled with
pdflatex --shell-escape main.tex 
pythontex main.tex
pdflatex --shell-escape main.tex 


pythontex scans the contents of the pycode environment verbatimly and searches for the stringified version of \end{pycode}. Your approach with environ can't work.

I guess your question is actually "How do I put a frame around a pycode environment?", isn't it?

The following collects the contents of foo as a box instead of as a macro argument, as a result stuff requiring category code changes (such as pycode) works. I also incorporated your own boxing mechanism using \[\] and a \framebox.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[makestderr]{pythontex}

\newsavebox\foobox
\newenvironment{foo}
  {%
    \begin{lrbox}{\foobox}%
      \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\textwidth-.25cm}%
  }
  {%
      \end{minipage}%
    \end{lrbox}%
    \[\framebox[\textwidth][c]{\usebox\foobox}\]%
  }

\begin{document}

foo:
\begin{foo}
\begin{pycode}
print(42)
\end{pycode}
\end{foo}

\end{document}



perfect! i was about to write a python program to parse the latex file, extract the body of the environment, run python on it, and replace the body with the stdout in a new latex file. you saved me a lot of work. thanks!!!

If your goal is to always use pycode inside your environment you can use the new enverb package that allows you to collect and then rescan the contents of your environment to directly use the nested pycode around your contents while nesting it however you need inside other LaTeX macros' arguments.
As a syntactic sugar enverb allows you to indent your verbatim material and automatically remove the needed indent based on the indentation of the \end statement (the package default removes two spaces more than whatever number is found in front of the matching \end, you can control this behaviour by using more-ignore=<num> to say it should ignore <num> tokens, or by setting auto-ignore=false to turn this off completely, or say ignore=<num> to always ignore a fixed number of tokens).
enverb doesn't support this as package options however, so you'll need to either use \enverbsetup to change this for your document, or \enverb{<key=value>} instead of the empty argument used in the following MWE.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[makestderr]{pythontex}

\usepackage{enverb}

\newenvironment{foo}
  {\enverb{}}
  {%
    \[%
      \framebox[\textwidth][c]%
        {\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-.25cm}{\enverbListing{pycode}{}}}%
    \]%
  }

\begin{document}

foo:
\begin{foo}
  print(42)
\end{foo}

\end{document}


